# last digit of four consecutive primes

Tags: prime-numbers

Since two consecutive primes ending in the same last digit has a probability less than mere chance, then four consecutive primes ending in the digits $1,3,7,9$
in any order will be greater than chance.  Examples of four primes ending in
the four different digits are $11,13,17,19$ and $23,29,31,37.$  Probability is
$\frac{4!}{4^4}=\frac{3}{32}$.  There can be two consecutive  sets of four each ending with the
same four digits: $47,53,59,61$ and $53,59,61,67$ with probability $\frac{3}{128}$.  There
can be three consecutive sets as in $1061,1063,1069,1087$ and $1063,1069,1087,1091 $ and $1069,1087,1091,1093$ with probability $\frac{3}{512}$.

Does anyone want to run through the first few thousand primes to see how the
results are better than mere chance four one set, two sets, three sets... having
this last digit property?  What's the largest string of consecutive primes
having the most sets of four moving from left to right?  Has anyone wondered if there are more groups of four like 11,13,17,19 with difference of first to last is eight than there are with a difference of greater than eight, as in 3331,3343,3347,3359?  What is the most common difference of such groups of four?

Comment: There are quite a few places with lists of primes on-line: e.g., http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php  Will that do?  Or are you looking for someone to do the data mining for you?

Comment: I looked at the primes up to 20,000 just by eyesight and NO computer.I found that four primes with this property happened about 1.5 times more than mere probability.  I just posed the question to get confirmation with a larger sample....this is of interest only to those passionate about primes  Have you ever wondered if there are more sets of four consecutive primes with the last digits 1,3,7,9 in order, as in 11,13,17,19 than there are for similar groups of  four that are NOT consecutive primes but merely increasing primes?  Maybe there are other questions to explore?.